# IntelliJ puts file header after package and imports

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, file-templates

I run IntelliJ 2023.3.3. The IDE settings are set to incorporate the file header first:

[image]

However, when a test file is created via <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + T</kbd> the header is inserted after the package and imported in the new file.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Tests have separate templates in the Code section. Did you modify them as well? https://i.imgur.com/M9AnW86.png.

Comment: @CrazyCoder no Junit file templates in my setup, thanks for the idea

Comment: Switch to the Code tab, you will see JUnit templates there.

Comment: The code tab! Make your comment the answer @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are JUnit 3/4/5 Test Class templates under the **Code** tab on your screenshot, you need to adjust them as well.

[image: JUnit templates]